# Public Assemblies property in MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild

There is a folder in Visual Studio which holds some of the public assemblies. Example for VS2022:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`.

I have a custom MSBuild project that builds my other .Net projects (it's for historical reasons). At the moment it has the following `AssemblySearchPaths: {TargetFrameworkDirectory};$(OutputDir);$(ExternalCustom);{GAC}`. As you can see it doesn't include the mentioned `PublicAssemblies` as I can't add this path as a hardcoded one. Said that I was wondering if there is a `MSBuild property` that holds this path.

Comment: No there isn't a built-in or standard property. You need to define your own property. This is for a project that will only be built on Windows? If yes, you can use the [vswhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/tools-for-managing-visual-studio-instances?view=vs-2022#using-vswhereexe) tool to locate Visual Studio.

Comment: @JonathanDodds It's so unfortunate :-(. Yes, it's for Windows only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't a built-in or standard property. You need to determine the correct path and define your own property.

Visual Studio 2017 and later include the [`vswhere`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/tools-for-managing-visual-studio-instances?view=vs-2022#using-vswhereexe) tool which can be used to determine the Visual Studio installation directory. `vswhere` when installed with Visual Studio is always in the "Program Files (x86)" directory in the sub-directory "Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer".

The sub-folder structure of the Visual Studio installation directory is stable. You should be able to use `<install dir>\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` for the `PublicAssemblies` directory.

An example of using `vswhere` from MSBuild and defining a property:

```xml
<Project>

  <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="GetVsInstallPath">
    <Message Text="VisualStudioInstallPath: '$(VisualStudioInstallPath)'" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PublicAssembliesPath>$(VisualStudioInstallPath)\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies</PublicAssembliesPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="PublicAssembliesPath:    '$(PublicAssembliesPath)'" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="GetVsInstallPath">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Enclose in quotes because of spaces in the directory names -->
      <VsWhere Condition="'$(VsWhere)' == ''">&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe&quot;</VsWhere>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Text="'$(VsWhere)' does not exist." Condition="Exists('$(VsWhere)')" />
    <Exec Command="$(VsWhere) -latest -property installationPath" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" EchoOff="true" StandardOutputImportance="Low">
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="VisualStudioInstallPath" />
    </Exec>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

There can be multiple installations of Visual Studio on the same machine. The `-latest` switch limits the output of `vswhere` to "only the newest version and last installed". Add the `-prerelease` switch if you want preview versions of Visual Studio to be considered. (At the time of writing there is a release version of VS2022 that supports up to .NET 7 and a preview version of VS2022 that supports the pre-release of .NET 8.0.)

The `-property installationPath` argument limits the output of `vswhere` to the `installationPath` and the entirety of the output can be used as the value of the `VisualStudioInstallPath` property.

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect a ready solution) It's both useful and working (verified it after some adoption to my environment. I owe you)